# Faceted query browser for SOLR

Tags: solr, faceted-search

Can you recommend a faceted query browser that I can point at a SOLR index?  Ideally this would be something that looks like an Endeca-built GUI, where the various facets are extracted from the index, the user clicks on one and is now shown the applicable facets for the remaining items, eventually culminating in a subset of the original data.  It's easy to make individual Lucene queries against the index but for debugging purposes I would rather use a pre-built browser than roll my own.

Answer (score 6):

[Collex](http://web.archive.org/web/20100528145738/http://www.patacriticism.org/collex/screenshots/) and [Blacklight](http://blacklight.rubyforge.org/) are two faceted Solr browsers, but I don't know if they're generic enough for your use-case.

EDIT: The Solr 3.2 distro now includes the contrib package [Solritas (AKA VelocityResponseWriter)](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter) that can be used as a generic faceted index browser.

Comment: The link to Collex seems to be broken, and I wasn't able to find a working link to it.